# Defining the background color of a Dash app in Julia

Tags: colors, background, julia, plotly-dash

I've built a Dash app to display a dataframe as a datatable. The code below:

```
df = DataFrame(Day=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"],
               Object=["Egg","Cat","Phone"],
               Letters=["A","B","C"],
               Food=["Milk","Egg","Cheese"])

colors=(background="#111111", text="#000000")

app = dash()

app.layout = html_div() do
    dash_datatable(id="data_table",
                   columns = tuple([(name=x,id=x) for x in names(df)])[1],
                   data = df_to_datatable(df),
                   style_cell = (textAlign="center", fontSize=16,
                                 backgroundColor="rgb(50,50,50)",
                                 color="white"),
               style_header = (backgroundColor="rgb(30, 30, 30)",),
               style_table = (textAlign="center", minwidth="35%",
                              width="35%",maxwidth="35%",
                              marginLeft="auto",marginRight="auto"),
              ),
    html_div(id="output_div")
end
```

results in the following table:

[image: Sample Dash datatable]

However, I'm having trouble defining the background color of the entire page. Based on [this](https://dash.plotly.com/layout) documentation, I've tried to define the background color when I call `html_div()`:

```
app.layout = html_div(style=(backgroundColor=colors.background)) do
```

which results in the error:

```
Invalid argument `style` passed into Div.
Expected `object`.
Was supplied type `string`.
Value provided: "#111111"
```

I checked that I'm passing the tuple "colors", but it's reading the definition of the tuple argument as a string. How can I pass it the argument it's looking for?

**Ultimately, I would like the white background to be blue.**

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
html_div(style=(backgroundColor=colors.background,))
```

That trailing comma is important to differentiate between assignment and the creation of a named tuple.